# Scilab - gui - axes auto_clean the graph during adjusting the slider ...?

Tags: scilab

I'm trying to create a simple GUI in scilab, just for display the graph of function a'sin(x), where a slider is driving the value of "a". I don't seem to find a way to display only the curve corresponding to the current value of "a"... it just add new curves to the existing ones. I hope there is a simple solution for this, as I cannot get further at the moment (I only have some experience with Mathematica). The very simple code I use is:

```
// This GUI file is generated by guibuilder version 3.0
//////////
f=figure('figure_position',[400,50],'figure_size',
[656,581],'auto_resize','on','background',[33],'figure_name','Graphic 
window number %d');
//////////
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('File'))
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('?'))
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('Tools'))
toolbar(f.figure_id,'off')
handles.dummy = 0;
handles.slider=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',
[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','Tahoma',
'FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal',
'ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left','ListboxTop',
[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.0359375,0.78125,0.2625,0.09375],
'Relief','default','SliderStep',
[0.01,0.1],'String','slider1','Style','slider','Value',
[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','slider',
'Callback','slider_callback(handles)')
handles.graph= newaxes();handles.graph.margins = [ 0 0 0 
0];handles.graph.axes_bounds = [0.31875,0.01875,0.6640625,0.925];

//////////
// Callbacks are defined as below. Please do not delete the comments as 
it will be used in coming version
//////////

function slider_callback(handles)
//Write your callback for  slider  here
x=0:0.1:10;
a=handles.slider.Value;
plot(x,a*sin(x));
endfunction
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default each graphic instruction add its result to the current display
If you want the figure to be erased automatically before a new graphic instruction is displayed you can set the auto-clear property of the axes to "on". An other solution is to erase the previous drawing using the delete function.

If you do not want the graduations to be displayed you can use the xpoly function instead of the plot function

```
// This GUI file is generated by guibuilder version 3.0
//////////
f=figure('figure_position',[400,50],'figure_size',...
[656,581],'auto_resize','on','background',[33],'figure_name','Graphic window number %d');
//////////
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('File'))
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('?'))
delmenu(f.figure_id,gettext('Tools'))
toolbar(f.figure_id,'off')
handles.dummy = 0;
handles.slider=uicontrol(f,'unit','normalized','BackgroundColor',...
[-1,-1,-1],'Enable','on','FontAngle','normal','FontName','Tahoma',...
'FontSize',[12],'FontUnits','points','FontWeight','normal',...
'ForegroundColor',[-1,-1,-1],'HorizontalAlignment','left','ListboxTop',...
[],'Max',[1],'Min',[0],'Position',[0.0359375,0.78125,0.2625,0.09375],...
'Relief','default','SliderStep',...
[0.01,0.1],'String','slider1','Style','slider','Value',...
[0],'VerticalAlignment','middle','Visible','on','Tag','slider',...
'Callback','slider_callback(handles)')
handles.graph= newaxes();
handles.graph.margins = [ 0 0 0 0];
handles.graph.axes_bounds = [0.31875,0.01875,0.6640625,0.925];
handles.graph.data_bounds=[0 -1.2;10 1.2];
handles.graph.auto_clear="on";
//////////
// Callbacks are defined as below. Please do not delete the comments as 
//it will be used in coming version
//////////

function slider_callback(handles)
//Write your callback for  slider  here
x=0:0.1:10;
a=handles.slider.Value;
drawlater()
//delete(handles.graph.children)
xpoly(x,a*sin(x))
handles.graph.data_bounds=[0 -1.2;10 1.2];
drawnow
//plot(x,a*sin(x));
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. Additionally, how can I make the x and y axes visible (using xpoly)? If I just keep the plot() function with auto_clear=on, after 2-3 times of moving the slider, I get the error "!--error 999 
set: The handle is not or no more valid." ... I don't really understand why...

Answer (score 0):

You can access the polyline of the graph and change the data (x,y) directly.
Place an empty (or dummy) plot somewhere (for instance close to the definition of your uicontrols).

Then in the callback function get the current axes object:

```
axes1=gca();// get the current axes
```

Assuming you plotted just one line, your polyline is then addressed by axes1.children.children (if you plotted multiple lines, they are addressed by axes1.children.children(1), axes1.children.children(2) and so on).

The x and y data are in "data" of the polylines, so you have to just update this data:

```
axes1.children.children.data=xymatrix([x1,y1;x2,y2;x3,y3;...xn,yn]);
```

Your callback function could look like the following:

```
function slider_callback(handles)
//Write your callback for  slider  here
x=zeros(101,2);//define matrix with 101 rows and 2 columns
x(:,1)=0:0.1:10;//fill first column with x axis values
a=handles.slider.Value;//get slider value
x(:,2)=a*sin(x(:,1));//fill second column with y axis values
axes1=gca();//get current axes
axes1.children.children.data=x;//update polyline data with new xy data
endfunction
```